# Pesquisa de campo quando abre uma modal

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Bom dia, estou fazendo um teste com o Selenium, ai quando vou fazer uma pesquisa dentro de um campo, ele abre um modal, não possibilitando a pesquisa quando clicado em um botão.
o erro que dá é esse, clico em um botão para realizar a pesquisa dentro do campo, e ele não me retorna nada.
//div[@id='formRegistroChamado:registroChamado-tipo_panel']/ul/li[8]